# Questions with no bounty appearing in Bountied section

Tags: bug, custom-filter

I was viewing [Bountied questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=Newest&filters=Bounty&edited=true) with specifically the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag selected and after some time, two questions appeared in the list that weren't even bountied. It seems that questions with new activity are bypassing the "Has Bounty" filter when a specific tag (in my case, [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)) is selected.

I refreshed the page and the unbountied questions were gone.

I am not sure if this is only a problem with the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag with "Has Bounty" filter checked, but it probably is a problem with other tags as well when viewing with the "Has Bounty" filter checked.

Can anyone look into this? it seems like a bug to me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think it's related to an existing bug where if you have a filter for `[tag-A] [tag-B]` you would see questions tagged only with *both* tags but the live updates show questions tagged [tag-B]. Unless the filter is explicitly `[tag-A] and [tag-B]` in which case new activity checks for both, while `[tag-A] or [tag-B]` will give you new activity for either. Only in this case, it's also looking at the bounty filter. See the bug report here: [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343767)

Comment: @VLAZ Hmm, that could be the case. I don't know how exactly the system works but for context I selected `php` tag and the "Has Bounty" checkmark at the same time and clicked "Apply Filter" instead of selecting php first, clicking "Apply Filter", and then selecting the "Has Bounty" checkmark and clicking "Apply Filter" again.

Comment: It's a pure guess on my part. I linked the bug report so, *assuming* this is related, it's maybe easier to track down the issues.

Comment: Maybe this is the phenomenon where newly asked questions will get live-updated into a filtered result even if they don't meet the filter?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Could be, though I think it also happens with questions of new activity, i.e., modified or recently answered questions.